# Forcing the compiler to use a certain register for a certain variable

Tags: c, linux, gcc, clang, x86-64

Is it possible to force a compiler (`gcc` or `clang` in my case) to use a certain register, lets say `R15` on `x86_64` for a certain variable and also prohibit it from using `R15` for any other purpose besides that variable.

Comment: Maybe http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Reg-Vars.html can help?

Comment: Why do you think you know better than the compiler how to handle register allocation?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler while I agree with your intent, the OP says _nowhere_ he thinks he knows it better. Maybe it's just as practice?

Comment: The last time I looked this was only possible for gcc, clang didn't implement this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, there are some applications for such hackery, e.g if you want to use an specific compiler instruction that needs a specific set of registers. Should be rare, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Some runtimes allocate one or several registers to often-used variables (OCaml does for a variable named `caml_young_ptr` that is used all the time). In this kind of context the pragma can make sense (and yes, traditional register allocation can produce code that is worse than the simple “always leave this variable in this register” heuristic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gcc can do it.

The already cited [gcc docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Reg-Vars.html) answers your question of how to force a variable into a certain register.

To stop the compiler from generating code using this register for other purposes, use the gcc switch `-ffixed-reg` (see gcc doc for details).

Comment: The reference to the [other Stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17809693/forcing-the-compiler-to-use-a-certain-register-for-a-certain-variable) above is a fantastic example of cross-reference!

Comment: It certainly reminds one of the classic dictionary meaning of recursion.  `recursion, n: See recursion`

Comment: The orignial link was a little bit messed up and I tried to edit it - but someone was faster (but got still the wrong link) - I fixed it now